# How to correctly use actionbar tabs when your code is almost the same on each fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I'm making an app with actionbar tabs, and the code of each fragment is almost the same... So i thought about using 1 fragment (passing the tab position to the fragment so it will know what to do on  onCreateView) but some developer said it was a pain to save the tab state.

I also thought about making a class and extend each fragment from there, still, the used code is almost the same and i ran into some troubles trying this.

So I'm not sure about the best way to do this, the app is working... but i hope you can help me to improve my design. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I'm making an app with actionbar tabs" -- note that action bar tabs are deprecated in the "L" Developer Preview and should remain deprecated in future versions of Android. Consider using something else for tabs, such as a `ViewPager` with a tabbed indicator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create similar fragments by creating a static method to create the fragment and set arguments.  When oncreate runs you access the arguments.  Pretty much the same as viewpager.

```
public class MainActionBarTabListFragment extends ListFragment {

public static MainActionBarTabListFragment newInstance(int sortOrder,ArrayList<String> tabsList) {
    MainActionBarTabListFragment f = new MainActionBarTabListFragment();

    // Supply num input as an argument.
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(SORT_ORDER, sortOrder);
    args.putStringArrayList(TAB_NAME, tabsList);
    f.setArguments(args);
    return f;
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle b = this.getArguments();
    if (b != null) {
        mSortOrder = b.getInt(SORT_ORDER, 0);
        tabsList = b.getStringArrayList(TAB_NAME);
    }

}



public class MainActionBarTabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

private ArrayList<String> tabsList;

public MainActionBarTabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<String> tabsList) {
    super(fm);
    this.tabsList = tabsList;
}

/** This method will be invoked when a page is requested to create */
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int fragmentPage) {
    MainActionBarTabListFragment fragment0 = MainActionBarTabListFragment
            .newInstance(fragmentPage, tabsList);
    return fragment0;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return tabsList.size();
}

}
```